# is it better to separate each customer container in a specific namespace or not?

Tags: security, kubernetes, logging, containers

I have a container that is needed per customer(about 5000 customers). For each customer that signs up on my website, one container goes up (with a different port) and the customer sends his/her logs to it, then logs are processed and ingested to the data storage container (one for all customers). in Kubernetes (In terms of security and other conditions), is it better to separate each customer container in a specific namespace or not?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter you can create the as many namespaces you want in Kertnetes however if you have any requirement to give K8s access to customers it would be better to separate them out by namespaces.

Keeping different containers themselves creates one layer of separation however if you still want to create a virtual env you can do it and use the namespace.